# Restrict Ubuntu user permissions

Tags: linux, shell, permissions

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 to host my application. The device that hosts the application will deliver to the client, meaning I would like to strip the regular desktop user from every permission.
After a research, I added to the user .bashrc file false aliases something like:

> alias ls="printf ''"

The problem is that the user can still write every command under a specific path:

> bin/su
> bin/cd

This way he has complete power over the system. I would love to get some help with this issue.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

solution for restrict the terminal
Create a group for terminal users

```
addgroup terminalusers
usermod -a -G terminalusers <user>
chown root:terminalusers /usr/bin/mate-terminal
chmod 750 /usr/bin/mate-terminal
```

After this process, the terminal would be blocked
Buenos - you can block every application you want with the command ***which***

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
addgroup <group-username>
usermod -a -G <group-username> <user>
chown root:<group-username> /usr/bin/<terminal-name>
chmod 750 /usr/bin/bash #permissions can be as per requirement like 760 etc
```

Ubuntu uses bash. On other distros we may have to see which shell and terminal they use e.g. gnome version of ubuntu has gnome terminal and bash. Kali has zsh (which I think is better).